# React-native Screen not redirecting

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator, react-native-tabnavigator

I'm trying to navigate From `libraries` screen to `Playlist` screen. but when I click the button it is not redirecting, it still shows the library screen!

**N.B:** I nested a stack navigator into a tab navigator.

Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

here is the code;

Stacknavigator

```
  const LibraryNav = createStackNavigator();

  return (
    <LibraryNav.Navigator headerMode="none">
      <LibraryNav.Screen name="LibraryScreen" component={LibraryScreen} />
      <LibraryNav.Screen name="PlaylistScreen" component={PlaylistScreen} />
      <LibraryNav.Screen name="AlbumsScreen" component={AlbumsScreen} />
    </LibraryNav.Navigator>
  );
};

Tabnavigator

      <Tab.Screen name="Music Library" component={withPlayer(LibraryNav)} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Saved" component={withPlayer(SongsScreen)} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Account" component={withPlayer(SettingsScreen)} />

LibrariesScreen

            <TouchableOpacity 
            onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('PlaylistScreen')}
            >
               <Text>Playlist Screen</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: pls add code snippet so that we can understand your question better.

Comment: Can you please attach your code. Also, provide proper info like what error you are getting.

Comment: @AnurodhSingh i just want to move from the libraries screen to the playlist screen but when i click the button it still shows the library screen

Comment: Try this, this.props.navigation.navigate('Saved');